# Left side margin not working on Carousel while hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

On hover, I want my images to shift the other images to the left and right. Currently, on hover, it shifts all the images to the right only.

With this code:

```
.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin: 0 70px 0 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;  
}
```

I would have thought I'd make the images on both sides shift. But nope - still only right!

So rather than the current effect (shifting right only)
[image]

I'm trying to make it shift both ways, like this
[image]

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

a.controls {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 6em;
  background: #000;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carousel-item:not(.active) {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-item .active {
  display: block !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.item-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 899;
}

.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin: 0 70px 0 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;
}

.item {
  height: 240.625px !important;
}

.item__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}

.item__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.item_title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover.item__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3 p-0">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="ld_Carousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item item active">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you need to look into [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Please, could you give an example, because looking at the docs I don't see how this would help in this situation?

Comment: this is how CSS and Divs behave when a div expands (on hover), the divs after it (to the right) would adjust - not the divs which have been rendered before it...

Comment: @AkberIqbal, is there a way to combat this?

Comment: @GerryHodson, check the answer which uses jquery to accomplish this

Comment: @GerryHodson, if you remove this linne **margin: 0 70px 0 70px;** from hover. then your hover will be work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use JQuery for the effect that you're looking for as the current behaviour is as per CSS rules... what I have done is that pushed the previous element a little more left so that it makes way for our image to zoom out...

**working snippet** below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).prev().css('margin-left', '-10px')
  });
  $("img").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).prev().css('margin-left', '0px')
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

a.controls {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 6em;
  background: #000;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carousel-item:not(.active) {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-item .active {
  display: block !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.item-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 899;
}

.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;
}

.item {
  height: 240.625px !important;
}

.item__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}

.item__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.item_title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover.item__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3 p-0">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="ld_Carousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item item active">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change/add below CSS it will work as expected-

```
.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.item-img:hover,
.item-img:hover ~ .item-img{
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

a.controls {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 6em;
  background: #000;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carousel-item:not(.active) {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-item .active {
  display: block !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.item-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 899;
}

.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.item-img:hover,
.item-img:hover ~ .item-img{
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.item {
  height: 240.625px !important;
}

.item__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}

.item__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.item_title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover.item__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3 p-0">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="ld_Carousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item item active">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like this example. it is working on snippet below:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

a.controls {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 6em;
  background: #000;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carousel-item:not(.active) {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-item .active {
  display: block !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.item-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 899;
}

.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;
}

.item {
  height: 240.625px !important;
}

.item__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}

.item__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.item_title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover.item__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3 p-0">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="ld_Carousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item item active">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```